# can GNU Makefile target not wait for the prerequisite commands to finish and just wait for a side file to be generated

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can GNU Makefile target not wait for the prerequisite commands to finish and just wait for a side file to be generated?

```
target_0: 
         target_0_script;
         touch target_0
target_1: target_0
        runs a script that generate a target_2_can_start_now.
        touch target_1

target_2: target_1
        runs some scripts
        touch target_2
```

What i want to do is that when do make target_2, it start execute target_0 then target_1 and immediately after target_2_can_start_now being created, target_2 starts and not wait for the whole script in target_1 to finish.

Comment: So the `target_2` recipe doesn't actually need the file `target_1`?

Comment: Any reason you don't simply use `make -j 2`? But if your comments are correct `target_2` should not depend on `taget_1`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you need to completely separate the build of `target_2_can_start_now` from that of `target_1`, if it is possible:

```
target_0: 
    target_0_script;
    touch target_0

target_2_can_start_now: target_0
    runs a script that generate a target_2_can_start_now.

target_1: target_2_can_start_now target_0
    touch target_1

target_2: target_2_can_start_now
    runs some scripts
    touch target_2
```

Comment: Thank you! I have updated the make version to latest. However, target_2 is still waiting for target_1 commands to finish and didn't start after target_2_can_start_now file is created.

Comment: Hmm! My bad, sorry. My answer was plain stupid (just edited it): make has no way to know when `target_2_can_start_now` is generated during the `target_1` build. So it waits until the end of the recipe. To achieve what you want you need to completely separate the build of `target_2_can_start_now` from that of `target_1`, I am afraid. Is it possible?

Comment: Note that this modification has the effect that `make target_2` will not cause `target_1` to be built.  This may be fine, but it is different from the original makefile.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Absolutely. I do not see another way to accelerate the beginning of `target_2` build than modifying the dependency tree.